# Which git commands have a <repository> parameter?

Tags: git

`git clone` takes a `<repository>` parameter per `git help clone`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   git clone [--template=<template_directory>]
             [-l] [-s] [--no-hardlinks] [-q] [-n] [--bare] [--mirror]
             [-o <name>] [-b <name>] [-u <upload-pack>] [--reference <repository>]
             [--dissociate] [--separate-git-dir <git dir>]
             [--depth <depth>] [--[no-]single-branch]
             [--recursive | --recurse-submodules] [--] <repository>
             [<directory>]
```

What is the full list of `git` commands that can be performed on a repository URL?

I am asking because I want to analyze remote repositories. Before I start a start scoping that out, and as a separate question, I am asking here about the git commands' capabilities.

Comment: Happy browsing: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/

Comment: The question is definitely peculiar but technically there's nothing wrong with it; it's clear and to the point. I suggest adding a little context or example of what that information would be used for just to calm trigger-happy close voters, though I guess it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @tne Thank you, adding clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ pwd
/usr/share/man/man1
$ zgrep -l '<repository>' git-*
git-clone.1.gz
git-fetch.1.gz
git-fetch-pack.1.gz
git-ls-remote.1.gz
git-pull.1.gz
git-push.1.gz
git-submodule.1.gz
git-subtree.1.gz
```